# Logic behind defining the pdf for trapz distribution in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

need help to understand the logic behind defining the pdf for trapz distribution in scipy.stats.

From Github Scipy.Stats repository its coded as:-

```
def _pdf(self, x, c, d):
    u = 2 / (d-c+1)

    return _lazyselect([x < c,
                        (c <= x) & (x <= d),
                        x > d],
                       [lambda x, c, d, u: u * x / c,
                        lambda x, c, d, u: u,
                        lambda x, c, d, u: u * (1-x) / (1-d)],
                        (x, c, d, u))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a chain of `if x < c : ... elif c < x < d: ... elif d < x : ...`, only for array-valued arguments. 
E.g., If you have an array `x`, different of its elements need different branches of this `if-elif` chain.